# How to store vector on a Solr field

Tags: solr

I have a field to store the vector data, which present as a float array. It will be computed with the vector from a query on the fly, so a `DocValues=true` property is needed to speed up the calculation. And I don't need to consider the retrieval-based(index) solution at this time.

To choose a proper field to store a float array in each document here is some possible field type:

1. BinaryField: this doesn't support the DocValues.
2. FloatPointField: this will use the `SORTED_NUMERIC` when this field is multi-valued, if you want to keep the original order, you need to enable `stored=true`, which will cause worse performance than `DocValues`.

Any suggestions?

My solr version is 6.6

- ref: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/docvalues.html